# Passing ICollection as a argument

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, icollection

I am stuck with this simple looking code for over an hour now...
I have few classes...and methods like this:

```
abstract class ClassBase<SampleInterface> {//Some methods};

public class ClassAction1: ClassBase<MyInterface> {//Some methods};

public class ClassAction2: ClassBase<MyInterface> {//Some methods};

class SomeClass
{ 
    public void AddClassRange(ICollection<ClassBase<MyInterface>> range)
    {
        foreach (ClassBase<MyInterface> ClassBase in range)
            AddClass(ClassBase);
    }


    public void AddClass(ClassBase<MyInterface> behavior)
    {
        // Something
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to use these codes in a different class:

```
var arg1 = new ClassAction1 {//Something};
var arg2 = new ClassAction2 {//Something};

//try1
sampleElement.AddClassRange(new [] { arg1 });   // works fine

//try2
sampleElement.AddClassRange(new [] { arg2 });   // works fine
```

I want to combine try1 and try2:

```
// Something like this (try3)
sampleElement.AddClassRange(new [] { arg1, arg2 });   // Error
Error : No best type found for implicitly typed array
```

As I think, In try1 and try2 runtime is deciding the `type` for keyword `new` based on the parameter passed to it. But in try3, parameters are of different types and runtime fails to decide for the best `type` for the `new` keyword.

Thanks. Let me know if need more info.

Comment: The problem is that it can't create a collection of a class, since arg1 and arg2 are different. Try casting them to the base type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicitly typed arrays only work when the type of the array element is the exact compile-time type of *one* of the elements. In other words, the compiler treats the set of element types as the set of *candidate* types, and then tries to find exactly one of those types to which all the other types can be implicitly converted.

In your case, the set of candidate types is `ClassAction1` and `ClassAction2`, neither of which is implicitly convertible to the other - which is why you're getting a compiler error. So you need to state the desired element type explicitly - presumably `ClassBase<MyInterface>`:

```
sampleElement.AddClassRange(new ClassBase<MyInterface>[] { arg1, arg2 });
```

Alternatively, you can cast either or both of the elements:

```
sampleElement.AddClassRange(new[] { (ClassBase<MyInterface>) arg1, arg2 });
```

Comment: @Saeed: no need, as there's an implicit conversion from ClassAction2. You just need the right type to be in the candidate set.

Comment: I have always been a fan of yours...today you made me your AC...lol...it worked great...you made my day...thanks

Answer (score 2):

just do:

```
sampleElement.AddClassRange
   (new [] { arg1 as ClassBase<MyInterface>,  arg2 as ClassBase<MyInterface>})
```

In fact, in one array you cannot have different object types. You should cast them to the same object type in your case because at last you have an object of type `ClassBase<MyInterface>` in your SomeClass, So you should cast it to `ClassBase<MyInterface>`. In your first sample this cast can be done implicitly but in your second sample it cannot.

Comment: Thanks...for your help...help appreciated